# Convert a txt file that uses space delimiter to tab delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that is importing pricing from various txt files that are automatically generated by a third party. I hit a road block with one of the txt files because it uses space delimited whereas the others use tab. Because of the space delimited, when i split the data i get different values in each column.

Here is what I have so far to open and read the text file

```
        usFileName = PathName & "\" & "Prices.txt"

        If fs.FileExists(usFileName) Then
            Set US = fs.OpenTextFile(usFileName, 1)

            theData = US.ReadLine
            getDate = Split(theData, Chr(0))
            curDate = Trim(Left(getDate(0), 10))

            If curDate = ActiveSheet.Range("Sheet_Date") Then
                    Do While Not US.AtEndOfStream
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Ln = US.ReadLine
                        Cols = Split(Ln, "  ")
                        Price = Trim(Cols(7))
                        NameTrim = Trim(Replace(Cols(1), "USO-", ""))
                        CellName = Replace(NameTrim, "-", "_") & "_" & Trim(Cols(2))

                        If ActiveSheet.Range(CellName) Is Nothing Then
                            ''Do Nothing here
                            On Error Resume Next
                        Else

                            Set TxtRng = ActiveSheet.Range(CellName)

                            If TxtRng = ActiveSheet.Range(CellName) Then
                                TxtRng.Value = Price
                            End If
                        End If
                    Loop

                Else
                    MsgBox ("The current sheet date does not match the US file import date.")
                End If

            US.Close
        Else
            MsgBox ("The file Prices.txt does not exist.")
        End If
```

This is what the txt file looks like:

```
01/11/2019 06:00 PM  USO-FOX-USO  E10           8.9929     0.0000
01/11/2019 06:00 PM  USO-FOX-USO  CON8HE10      1.3212    -0.0244
01/11/2019 06:00 PM  USO-FOX-USO  CON8HE10TT    1.3232    -0.0244
```

And this is what the Cols variable looks like.

[image: Cols Output]
[image: Cols Output 2]

Comment: The way you use `On Error Resume Next` is a very bad practice. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them because it makes you blind. But the issue is that you cannot fix error that you don't see. If you don't fix them your code doesn't work. Remove these `On Error Resume Next` lines completely and fix the errors you get properly.

Comment: The errors that I am getting are because the cell name doesn't exist or it can't match up the cell correctly. I understand it is bad practice, but the errors that it is ignoring don't concern me at this point.

Comment: Then fix it that way, that it **only** ignores the specific errors you want and not **every** error as it does at the moment. You cannot debug/work on your code in this state as it is properly. Make sure `On Error Resume Next` is exactly before the line where you expect the error and use `On Error Goto 0` right after the line you expect the error to re-enable error reporting! Also see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Note that `On Error Resume Next` will not only hide the **next** error message as it looks like. Instead it hides **all** messages until `On Error Goto 0` or `End Sub`

Comment: I removed it, and there were no errors.

Comment: OK, now we can work on the code ;) It looks like this txt file is using fixed length for each field. So you must count how many characters each field has and use the [Mid function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) to split each line apart. Alternatively you might want to have a look at the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.TextToColumns) using `DataType:=xlFixedWidth`.

Comment: Also using [QueryTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable) with [QueryTable.TextFileParseType property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.textfileparsetype) `xlFixedWidth` might be an option here.

Comment: It looks as if your suggestions are importing the entire txt file into a sheet versus just reading the txt file and splitting the rows based on a delimiter into an array. So I may be confused on how to use them.

Comment: My first suggestion using `Mid()` would fit into your approach. You would use it on your `Ln` variable to extract each data field by their field length. • My second idea splits a text that is in a cell eg A1 into multiple columns (therefore the text needs to be already imported in a cell, you would need to put the complete `Ln` into a cell first). • My third idea is completely different form your approach and queries the txt file directly (incl. splitting fields by fixed width). You would start from scratch here.

Comment: How do you want it to split?  `Power Query`, aka `Get & Transform` can usually handle any particular delimiter, although, if you do this in code, you may have to write some code to detect the delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing spaces and replacing them this way:

```
    Ln = US.ReadLine
    Do While (InStr(Ln, "  ") > 0)
        Ln = Replace(Ln, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    'The only problem I see is the case where you have Time (6:00 PM) this 
    '    would replace the space with Tab. in that case, I would do the following:
    Ln = Replace(Ln, " PM", "PM")
    Ln = Replace(Ln, " AM", "AM")
    Ln = Replace(Ln, " ", vbTab)

    'And then put them back
    Ln = Replace(Ln, "PM", " PM")
    Ln = Replace(Ln, "AM", " AM")

    'Finally, split the columns
    Cols = Split(Ln, vbTab)
```

If you want to try with fixed width then do the following (after Ln = US.Readline):

```
    '01/11/2019 06:00 PM  USO-FOX-USO  E10           8.9929     0.0000    
    'Do the following only if (InStr(Ln, "  ") > 0)
    strCol1 = Mid(Ln, 1, 21)  
    strCol2 = Mid(Ln, 22, 13)  
    strCol3 = Mid(Ln, 35, 13)  
    strCol4 = Mid(Ln, 48, 11)  
    strCol5 = Mid(Ln, 59, Len(Ln))
```

Comment: Yeah, i've tried to do this. Even when i import the file into excel using something like Power Query, it throws a fit too. The only way to get the columns i need is to use a fixed with.

Comment: OK, I added an additional section of code at the end of my answer. Try that out.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 Be careful, you cannot remove the spaces. This will crash your data, eg if one field is empty all other fields will move one field left then! So the position of the data changes column. This can only be solved with fixed length fields.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I supplied the OP with two different options. If you look at the 2nd you will see that I offered a fixed width version as well (with just the mid function). Thx tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub Test()

    Dim PathName As String
    Dim usFileName  As String

    PathName = "Your path"
    usFileName = PathName & "\" & "Prices.txt"

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=usFileName, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), _
        Array(19, 1), Array(32, 1), Array(48, 1), Array(55, 1))

End Sub
```